# Multiple entries under the same user id

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a webapp on a pet shop. A user may have multiple visits to the pet shop. So the unique about the data is phone number of the user. But every time the same user visits the pet shop the data must be entered under the same user. I am having trouble coming up with a solution.

Comment: Wouldn't adding the visit date be a unique piece of information?  But at the moment there is very little information in your question to help with, what is your database design, what information are you storing etc?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you add more details to your question. It will also help if you describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: So a user may visit the pet shop multiple times for vaccination for their pet. I have built a database already consisting of userid, phone number, pet, vaccination, previous vaccination date and next vaccination date. So a user may come for their pets vaccination  multiple time leading multiple entry under the same user. I am having trouble doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two table one for users and another for visits as below
Table structure for table `users`

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

-- Table structure for table `visits`

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, but how do I view all the entries in the second table of the same userid in one report? How do I connect them?

Comment: use below query for get unique visits of user 
`SELECT v.*, u.* FROM visits as v LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id=v.user_id GROUP BY v.user_id ORDER BY v.id DESC`

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the following method

1. create **users** table where mobile no. or a unique userId will be present.
2. create **Visitors** table where you can store rest of the data of that user